# WCF client reference not generated correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, reference

From past few days I am facing error related to WCF service reference, my project was working fine but suddenly I am getting 100's of errors:

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Trade_ERP.ConfigurationRef.MaterialGroup1[]' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'  E:\Trade_ERP\Models\Configuration\MaterialManagement\MaterialGroup1Model.cs 13  20  Trade_ERP
>
> Error 6   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Trade_ERP.ConfigurationRef.ValuationClass[]' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'  E:\Trade_ERP\Models\Configuration\MaterialManagement\ValuationClassModel.cs 14  20  Trade_ERP

.
.
.

Everything was working fine but I don't know what happened / went wrong, so that this errors are coming.

And in our office, only on one PC it is working fine.

Comment: I don't kknow what went wrong but try to look at the config of you service reference and check the defaults of the collection type. Maybe these settings are wrong ;-)

Comment: i checked the config file but it is the same as working project Config file. Only the reference file is different.I don't know why it is different now.:(

Answer (score 0):

Check the references in the project where the service reference is added. It might be possible  that on the working computer you will find less dll files referenced.

Maybe you have referenced a dll/project which contains classes as MaterialGroup1 and ValuationClass. If so, WCF will reuse those types when generating the proxy.

If this is the case, you will have to click on configure, then select "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies" and check all the assemblies, except the one that contains those classes.

This way WCF will generate new classes even if there are other compatible types referenced in your application.

Comment: i did this but when i checked the reference file on working PC and mine then there are lots of difference present in both files

Comment: Then I think you should take a look on the proxy file from the working computer. Look for the generated methods on your ServiceClient class and navigate to the definition of input and output parameter types. If one of the types is outside that file (in another assembly), then on the non-working computer you have to check that assembly as well (so that the add/update reference will use that assembly instead of creating new classes)

Comment: working code **bold** `public System.Data.DataSet GetCurrDeterminTableDetail(string argToCurrencyCode, string argFromCurrencyCode, string argRateDate, string argClientCode) {
            return base.Channel.GetCurrDeterminTableDetail(argToCurrencyCode, argFromCurrencyCode, argRateDate, argClientCode);
        }`

Comment: not working code **bold** `public System.Data.DataSet GetCurrDeterminTableDetail(string argToCurrencyCode, string argFromCurrencyCode, string argRateDate, string argClientCode) {
Trade_ERP.ConfigurationRef.GetCurrDeterminTableDetailRequest inValue = new Trade_ERP.ConfigurationRef.GetCurrDeterminTableDetailRequest();
inValue.argToCurrencyCode = argToCurrencyCode;
inValue.argFromCurrencyCode = argFromCurrencyCode;inValue.argRateDate = argRateDate;
inValue.argClientCode = argClientCode;
Trade_ERP.ConfigurationRef.GetCurrDeterminTableDetailResponse`

Comment: retVal = ((Trade_ERP.ConfigurationRef.IwsConfigurationMaster)(this)).GetCurrDeterminTableDetail(inValue);
return retVal.GetCurrDeterminTableDetailResult;}`